# Docker Swarm using remote servers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

What I want to accomplish is creating Swarm manager in one server and a worker on a different server. For this I'm using the following commands:
- First I create the discovery service with:

```
    docker-machine create -d virtualbox mh-keystore
    eval "$(docker-machine env mh-keystore)"
docker run -d \
     -p "8500:8500" \
     -h "consul" \
     progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

Then I create the manager:

```
    docker-machine create \
     -d virtualbox \
     --swarm --swarm-master \
     --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \
     --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \
     --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \

 mhs-demo0
```

So far so good the problem is now when I create the worker on another server:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
     --swarm \
     --swarm-discovery="consul://IP:8500" \
     --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://IP:8500" \
     --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \
   mhs-demo1
```

How can I accomplish this without being it locally? I can only find tutorials online for doing it locally...

Thanks for the help
Sérgio Mendes

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the 'old' Swarm and not Swarm Mode?

Comment: Yes for my thesis I'm extending Swarm scheduling algorithm with the purpose of comparing with random, binpack and spread

Comment: OK cool. So, I don't really understand the question. When you say 'without all being locally' do you mean, you don't want to use virtualbox and local VMs? You want to use cloud machines? Or somethhing else?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try to rephrase. I have 7 different servers. 1 of them is going to be the manager and the other 6 will be workers. I will be  using virtualbox to create the manager and workers at the different servers. The problem I'm having is that I'm not being able to make the workers being able to join the swarm created by the manager

Comment: What are the IP addresses you are using? Is the `mh-keystore` actually available publicly to the `mhs-demo1` server? It sounds like `mh-keystore` and `mhs-demo0` are listing on local IP addresses that `mhs-demo1` cannot connect to.